# NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest don't reload data later

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection, reload

I have a problem.

I send a NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest for save data, and navigate to the next view. The next view send a other NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest, and load the data for show.

The problem are that when I make the NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest, don't receive the new data saved, but if I reload the second view data, or I put a delay in de second view load data, the data is loaded.

The delay option are bad solution.

Can help me please?

Thanks.

Comment: We need code to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're synchronously pushing data to a server, then changing views, then synchronously downloading data from the server, and you're not getting the data back that you just saved? It sounds to me like it's a problem with your server. I'd also suggest not using synchronous NSURLConnections at all, because any sort of latency or server issues will block the main thread, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, you understand correctly. When I write a information in the app view, I send these information with sendSynchronousRequest and inmediately pop the view and reload the data and if I can't put a delay time for reload data, and the new data send with sendSynchronousRequest in previously view can't see if I don't reload the view with the reload button on these view or if I put a delay for load the data.